# Prove that kernel of a transformation is a subset of the composite transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Let 
 T:L→L

Be a linear transformation. Prove that 
 ker(
  T
 )⊆ker(
  
   T∘T
 )
.

I tried classical 
 ker(
  T
 )⊆L

and postulated that since composite transformations keep their properties such as being injection, surjection or bijection, this implication is true

(
  
   ker(
    T
   )⊆L∧ker(
    
     T∘T
   )⊆L
 )⇒ker(
  T
 )⊆ker(
  
   T∘T
 )
.

But it doesn't seem right.

Comment: If $Tx = 0$, what can you say about $T(T(x))$?

Comment: The zero vector is always in the kernel of the transformation. Use that and the definition of kernel to complete the proof.

Comment: $$T\left( x \right) = 0 \Rightarrow T\left( {T\left( x \right)} \right) = T\left( 0 \right) = T\left( {\overrightarrow O  \cdot 0} \right) = 0 \cdot T\left( {\overrightarrow O } \right) = 0 \Rightarrow \ker \left( {T\left( x \right)} \right) = \ker \left( {T\left( {T\left( x \right)} \right)} \right)$$ Is that right?

Comment: @tomashauser You can only conclude that $\operatorname{ker}(T) \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(T \circ T)$, not that they are equal.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why is that. I guess $$\ker \left( T \right) \subseteq \ker \left( {T \circ T} \right)$$ means $$\left| {\ker \left( T \right)} \right| \le \left| {\ker \left( {T \circ T} \right)} \right|$$ where $$\left|  -  \right|$$ is cardinality. So I know that this means that there is a surjection. But why not bijection? Composite of T can't have a bigger kernel right?

Comment: @tomashauser Yes, $T \circ T$ can have a bigger kernel than $T$. For example, if $T = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ then the kernel of $T$ is the subspace of all vectors of the form $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. But $T \circ T$ is the zero matrix, which has kernel equal to all of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v\in \ker(T).$ Then, by definition of kernel, $T(v)=0_L$.

Applying $T$ to the null vector of $L$, we have that

$$T(0_L)=T(T(v))=\left(T\circ T\right)(v)$$

On the other hand,

$$T(0_L)=T(0_L+0_L)=T(0_L)+T(0_L)$$

Then, $T(0_L)=0_L$, i.e, $\left(T\circ T\right)(v) = 0_L$. Therefore, $v \in \ker(T\circ T)$. By the arbitrariness of $ v $, the result follows

Comment: Aren't you mixing different notations? I think that $$T \circ T\left( {\overrightarrow v } \right)$$ is quite confusing.

Comment: @tomashauser By definition, $T \circ T(v) = T(T(v))$. This is what function composition means.

Comment: Ok, so we know that $$T\left( {\overrightarrow v } \right) = \overrightarrow O .$$ Then we show that $$T\left( {\overrightarrow O } \right) = \overrightarrow O $$ which implies $$T\left( {T\left( {\overrightarrow v } \right)} \right) = T\left( {T\left( {\overrightarrow O } \right)} \right) = T\left( {\overrightarrow O } \right) =  {\overrightarrow O }$$ therefore $$v \in \ker \left( {T \circ T} \right),$$ right?

Comment: $T(T(v))=T(T(0))$ is not necessary. $T(T(v))=T(0)=0$ is enough to show what you want. But of course you need to show that $T(0)=0$

Comment: Nice, I get it now.